# Unable to get Foundation working out of the box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I thought I followed the directions, but maybe I missed something?

Gemfile:
`gem 'foundation-rails'`

ran `bundle`

ran `rails g foundation:install`

This added and made changes to:

views/layouts/application.html.erb

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "foundation-rails" %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

  <body>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

assets/stylesheets/application.css

```css
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides

 */
```

assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss

```css
// -- snip --

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// $include-html-visibility-classes: $include-html-classes;
// $include-accessibility-classes: true;
// $include-table-visibility-classes: true;
// $include-legacy-visibility-classes: true;

@import 'foundation';
```

assets/javascripts/application.js

```ruby
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

I have successfully seen buttons display correctly, but other things just refuse to display as expected.  The first thing I looked at was the grid example, so i copied and pasted the source, but it didn't shade as the example.  The spacing seems correct...

Then I tried accordian.  I copied and pasted from the source code of the examples. It displayed the list bullets but didn't expand/contract.

Then I tried the top bar.  I copied and pasted from the source code of the examples.  It put a horizontal bar at the top, but the menu items are not inline.

Then I tried making a brand new rails project just to test foundation.  I followed the same steps, and got the same results.  (mumbles something about insanity...)

I've used foundation before, but apparently I'm missing something important.

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

foundation-rails gem currently loads foundation 5, while the website has examples for foundation 6.  It would appear that they are NOT compatible ;)

To test, see the [documentation for foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/applications.html)